Finding possible sums of $ab+bc+ca$
The problem says,
Find all possible sums of $ab+bc+ca$ that satisfy the given condition:
$$|a+b+c| = ab+bc+ca < 3$$
I first tried using the identity $$(a+b+c)^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+2(ab+bc+ca),$$  but it didn't work well for me.
How can I solve it?

Are $a,b,c$ naturals (including $0?$), integers, or reals?  It seems likely there are many solutions in the reals.

First $3 > ab + bc + ca \ge 0$ and $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge ab + bc + ca$, then
$$(a+b+c)^2 \ge 3 (ab + bc + ca) = 3 |a + b+c|$$
That means either $|a+b+c|=0$ or $|a+b+c|\ge 3$ but that contradicts the assumption. The only possible case is $|a+b+c| = 0$.

Nitpicking, you should also show that the case can be achieved (else the answer is no solution).

@CalvinLin, ahh, you are right, it seems all variables taking zero is a straightforward case.
